# Assigning command prompt data into a python variable

Tags: python, command-prompt

I am trying to retrieve svn log information of a file in a subversion repository, which later needs to be dumped into a CSV.

Apparently, I run the following command using python os package

Code:

```
filePath = r"C:\Project_Files\My_Project\file1.c" # My_Project is in Subversion
svn_command = "svn log " + filePath + "-v > C:\\information.txt"
os.system(svn_command)
```

I get the svn log data in the information.txt but performing this kind of operation for several files (writing to txt and reading from txt) is very time consuming.

**Is there a way to automatically assign the data obtained from `svn log -v` into a python variable?**

Comment: Hi @SuryaTej, you can use `subprocess.Popen` for this, check my answer below :)

Comment: Thank you @DeveshKumarSingh your subprocess.Popen approach worked for me

Comment: Glad to help @SuryaTej  and thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for this, note that I am splitting up the command into a list, you can create that list beforehand

```
import subprocess

filePath = r"C:\Project_Files\My_Project\file1.c" # My_Project is in Subversion
svn_command = "svn log " + filePath + "-v > C:\\information.txt"

#Split command into individual words
cmd_list = svn_command.split()

#Run command via subprocess Popen
cmd_output = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

#Get output and error 
cmd_output, cmd_err = cmd_output.communicate()

#Get output and error string
cmd_output_str = cmd_output.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
cmd_err_str = cmd_err.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
```

A working example will be

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'uname -a'

#Split command into individual words
cmd_list = cmd.split()

#Run command via subprocess Popen
cmd_output = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

#Get output and error
cmd_output, cmd_err = cmd_output.communicate()

#Get output and error string
cmd_output_str = cmd_output.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
cmd_err_str = cmd_err.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()

print(cmd_output_str)
print(cmd_err_str)
```

The output here will be

```
Darwin LUSC02WK0GKHTDH 18.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0: Mon Mar 11 20:40:32 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.251.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```